# How to start a javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformation in a non-default XSLT mode?

Tags: java, xslt

XSLT supports different modes for its match templates. Processing starts in the default unnamed mode, but can be changed with each call to `<xsl:apply-templates/>`. However, I want to *start* the XSLT processing in a non-default mode.

The code I am working with currently uses a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` instance to load the XSLT stylesheet and perform the transformation. Is there any way with this approach to specify in Java which mode I would like the transformation to start with? I cannot find any. In case it matters, the stylesheet itself is in XSLT version 2.0.

I know it is possible with Saxon, by calling `net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.setInitialMode(QName)`, but I am asking for any solutions with the Java built-in solution: `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAXP interface was designed for XSLT 1.0 which does not allow you to select a non-default initial mode.

Saxon includes various extensions to the JAXP interface to get around such restrictions: cast the JAXP `Transformer` to `net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl` and call `setInitialMode()`.

But once you start using Saxon extensions to the JAXP interface, there's very little reason to prefer JAXP over Saxon's native s9api interface - especially when you start using XSLT 3.0 capabilities, which Saxon doesn't provide via JAXP at all.

Comment: Would any `xsl:stylesheet default-mode="foo-mode" ` work with JAXP and Saxon 9.8 and later to use that mode as the initial mode?.

Comment: Yes, I think so. But of course, there's nothing in JAXP that says how this should work; it's just Saxon trying to do what makes most sense.

Comment: Many thanks, this approach worked (as we are using Saxon under the hood)! I agree it would be preferable to use Saxon's native s9api interface, but was trying to avoid having to rewrite the our entire transformation scaffolding to make it work for a single new unit test which required an explicit initial mode.